# After Login using phone authentication in firebase if I sign out is there any way to login with same number?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I am using phone number authentication to login into my Mobile App. It's working fine !! I have also created a sign-out option for users. If the user signs out from the app. I didn't know how to login into my app using the same number. I can do this process using Gmail & password authentication. But I want to login into my app using the same phone number.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. What is keeping you from signing in again with the same number?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen If I sign out how can I sign in again without a phone number?

Comment: Google SmartLock which is backed by Google AutoFill Service seems to keep your credentials after asking you. I don't think the number is kept in that case. Do you want to do some kind of autofilling?

Comment: *If I sign out how can I sign in again without a phone number?* In the same way you did before. What's the problem when you try to do that?

Comment: @gtxtreme I didn't want auto-filling I want that credential for phone number login !!!

Comment: Do you mean the auth token that the Google SDK gives you? You can't have that, you have to initiate the flow again. I mean both the answers above are from Google people so if this is the case they will be able to tell you